# Тут получается одно лексическое окружение?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f() {
  let count = 0;

  return function() { return count++ };
}

let arr = [f(), f(), f()];

console.log( arr )

// тут полчается функции сылаются на одно лексическое окружение ?
// или каждый раз при вызове f()  создается уникальное лексичесоке окружение и его ни как не обойти ?
```

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под термином "лексическое окружение"?

Comment: @Grundy https://learn.javascript.ru/closure#sborka-musora

Comment: @Grundy Как Вы относитесь к этой статье ?

Comment: никак, смотри спецификацию - лучший источник, и проблем с терминологией не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kаждый раз при вызове `f()` создается уникальное лексическое окружение. (Не понял, что Вы хотите "обойти" и зачем.) То есть в Вашем примере их три.

А так - создается одно:

```js
function f() {
  let count = 0;

  return function() { return count++ };
}

let inc = f();
let arr = [inc(), inc(), inc()];

console.log( arr )
```

Comment: формально в твоем примере их 5 - глобальное, f, и 3 inc

Comment: @Igor Хотел узнать если несколько раз подряд вызывать функцию inc то у них будет общее лексическое окружение ( да или нет ); если нет то как можно обойти ( просто чтоб знать; можно обойти да или нет )